# const expressions and const array

Tags: dart, constants

In Dart, I define the following constants:

```
const aConstNum = 0;
const aConstBool = true;
const aConstString = 'a constant string';
const aConstList = const [1, 2, 3];
```

Then I define a `const string` with:

```
const validConstString = '$aConstNum $aConstBool $aConstString $aConstList';
```

However, I get the error: `aConstList is not constant`. But I defined `aConstList` to have constant value, and it should get evaluated at compile time. What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer by carefully reading the documentation;

> Literal strings are compile-time constants, as long as any
> interpolated expression is a compile-time constant that evaluates to
> null or a numeric, string, or boolean value.

It seems that it must explicitly eval to null, numeric, string or boolean neither of which is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Using Dart 2.19.1, I get a different error, one which is more helpful:

> The constant value '[1, 2, 3]' can't be used as part of a string interpolation in a constant expression.  Only values of type 'null', 'bool', 'int', 'double', or 'String' can be used.

I'm not sure why this limitation exists, or why your error message wasn't as helpful, but it seems clear that not only does the value need to be constant, but it needs to be one of the given types; a List isn't able to be interpolated in a constant string even if it is constant.